# Can't click on next button Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to have selenium click on the next page button at this site after clicking the submit button and getting pages of results: https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/search

I have tried countless ways to have selenium click on this button.  The html code for the next page button on the results page is here:

```
<button class="mat-paginator-navigation-next mat-icon-button" mat-icon-button="" type="button" aria-describedby="cdk-describedby-message-8" cdk-describedby-host="" aria-label="Next page" style="touch-action: none; user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);"><span class="mat-button-wrapper"><svg class="mat-paginator-icon" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6z"></path></svg></span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple mat-button-ripple-round" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button>
```

I've tried the following:

```
link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rsltToolbar"]/mat-paginator/div/div/div[2]/button[2]')
link.click()
```

But the code does not work.  Hopefully this is the button that needs to be clicked!  I've tried by css selector, class_name, by javascript etc. to no avail.  Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
link = driver.find_element_by_classname("mat-paginator-navigation-next")
```

should work fine

```
# (tested in js console with)
document.querySelector(".mat-paginator-navigation-next").click()
```

you might have to just add a delay (ie its probably not clickable initially(or clicking it too soon just does nothing))  I think you can wait for it to be clickable somehow

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
Thread.sleep(4000);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='rsltToolbar']/mat-paginator/div/div/div[2]/button[2]")).click();
```

XPath you have tried is working just need to add delay after you click "Search" on page"https://elibrary.ferc.gov/eLibrary/search"